# keycloak:javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request while creating a new realm

Tags: java, realm, keycloak

i am trying to create a new realm from master realm using keycoak-admin-client here is my code

```
val keyclaok = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
          .serverUrl("http://0.0.0.0:8080/auth")
          .realm("master")
          .username("admin")
          .password("admin")
          .clientId("admin-cli")
          .resteasyClient(
            new ResteasyClientBuilder()
              .connectionPoolSize(10).build()
          ).build()
val realm = new RealmRepresentation
        realm.setRealm("testrealm")
        keyclaok.realms().create(realm)
```

i am getting

```
javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:219)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.DefaultEntityExtractorFactory$3.extractEntity(DefaultEntityExtractorFactory.java:50)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:151)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.lufz.authentication.controllers.AuthenticationController.$anonfun$createRealm$2(AuthenticationController.scala:288)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive$.$anonfun$addByNameNullaryApply$2(Directive.scala:166)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.ConjunctionMagnet$$anon$2.$anonfun$apply$3(Directive.scala:234)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRouteResult$2(BasicDirectives.scala:68)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:161)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRequestContext$2(BasicDirectives.scala:45)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:161)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$2(RouteConcatenation.scala:47)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:40)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension(FastFuture.scala:44)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.flatMap$extension(FastFuture.scala:25)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives.$anonfun$handleExceptions$2(ExecutionDirectives.scala:32)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRouteResultWith$2(BasicDirectives.scala:74)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:161)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives.$anonfun$handleExceptions$2(ExecutionDirectives.scala:32)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route$.$anonfun$createAsyncHandler$1(Route.scala:110)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsyncUnordered$$anon$31.onPush(Ops.scala:1400)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:541)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:423)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:625)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:502)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:600)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:769)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:784)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:691)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:577)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience you need to provide more information for the realm representation to create:

```
val realm = new RealmRepresentation
        realm.setId("testRealmId")
        realm.setRealm("testRealm")
        realm.setEnabled(true) // may be unecessary
        keyclaok.realms().create(realm)
```